# Grouping various custom UIViews together to scale and translate them as a group

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have a bunch of `subviews`, which I want to move together as a group and scale up or down as a group, so to achieve this I added them to a `wrapperView`(UIView) and added `pan` and `pinch` `gestures` to this `wrapperView`. Now when I move and  pinch the `wrapperView` the `subviews` move together and are scaled together. But after relocating and resizing them. I want to add them to their original `parentView`. This is where I'm facing issues. These `subviews` which I want to move together are `custom UIViews`, with `UIImageView` as their `subviews`, So I'm unable to move them to the original `parentView` with their **new positions** and their **new sizes**. Please tell me what is happening here. This is how I add the subviews back to the parentView.

```
for(CustomUIView* v in wrapperView.subviews)
        {
            CGPoint location = [parentView convertPoint:v.frame.origin
                                                            fromView:wrapperView];
            v.frame.origin = location;
            [v removeFromSuperview];
            [parentView addSubview:v];
        }
```

Please help as I'm really stuck at a dead end here, and can't seem to understand how to go about doing this. Any help is appreciated, thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: The subviews are not added to the `location` coordinates and their size return to their original sizes, not their scaled sizes.

Comment: Your wrapper view has a transform on it; your actual subviews' frames etc. are not changing but are warped at display time by the transformed coordinate system in your wrapper view (subviews are ignorant of coordinate system changes in their superviews).  Presuming that all the views are together in the hierarchy, you should be able to call [parentView convertRect:v.bounds fromView:v], then call [v removeFromSuperview]; [v setFrame:<frame you got above>]; [parentView addSubview:v];.  That should convert to the rect seen by the superviews.